# SQL - select row of group with lowest column value grouped by other

Tags: sql, select

Hy there,

I have this table

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | hello | 1 |
| two | hello | 2 |
| three | hi | 3 |
| four | hi | 4 |

I want to select the minimum "C" value row grouping by B value

my output should be

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | hello | 1 |
| three | hi | 3 |

How I could select them?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Some products have a nice shortcut for the task.

Comment: postgres. c column values is large number..not a row number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically a solution for `row_number`

```
select a, b, c
from (
    select *, 
        Row_Number() over(partition by b order by c) rn
    from t
)t
where rn=1
```